# How do I merge characters (char) into a string in Java (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, bioinformatics

I'm trying to build a program that will represent Strings of Nucleotides using simple graphics. Nucleotides (A,C,G,T) are the character variables in the sequence of data that I have declared in a class called 'NucleotideSequence', which I want to use an input of to return a String value in a class called 'CodonObject' - a Codon is a group of 3 Nucleotides that is 'read off' in the nucleotide sequence in discrete steps and incrementally with no overlap, for example, ATG = first codon, GCC = second codon. String 'CodonObject' = "ATGGCC"

Each and every CodonObject has only 3 nucleotides contained within it and there will be multiple (100's) Codon-objects generated.

Any help or advice will be most gratefully received!

This I have so far:

```
public class NucleotideSequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
         new NucleotideSequence(); 
    } 
    public NucleotideSequence() { 
         char adenine = 'A'; 
         char cytosine = 'C'; 
         char guanine = 'G'; 
         char thymine = 'T'; 
    } 
public class CodonObject { 
    public String CodonObject(char nuc1, char nuc2, char nuc3)
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I'll copy and paste below the code to the program thus far - I'm just a beginner to programming unfortuantley - perhaps being a bit overambitious!                                                 public class NucleotideSequence
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     new NucleotideSequence();
    }
    
    public NucleotideSequence()
    {
     char adenine = 'A';
     char cytosine = 'C';
     char guanine = 'G';
     char thymine = 'T';
    }

public class CodonObject
{
 public String CodonObject(char nuc1, char nuc2, char nuc3)

Comment: Please add this to your original post, with the correct formatting. I have edited the post for now, but for future reference, you should format your posts correctly so that it is readable.

Comment: Apoligies Makri, thanks for your patience!

Comment: No problem. I must ask though, is your question how do you merge the char-values above into a string? And will every CodonObject have only 3 nucleotides, at all times, and will there be several Codon-objects? If so, you should create a constructor to your class that sets the nucleotides belonging to that Codon, and then create a get-method that returns the nucleotides as a string. Please update if this is what you really mean, we can help you better then.

Comment: Yes Makri that is completely correct - though for the final program there will be more than several (more like 100's) of codon objects. I will try to edit my original posting so that I communicate clearly my intention for the functioning of the program.

Comment: Well, will these CodonObjects have their own name, or will you write out the nucleotides to screen, or to file or what? And where do the nucleotides come from, a file or user input?

Comment: Each and every CodonObject is a copy/clone of a template that takes the form of a square - each side of the square represents a discrete nucleotide(A,C,G,T). The strings of nucleotide data come from www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov (an example here is the link to Insulin nucleotide data - www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/CCDS/CcdsBrowse.cgi?REQUEST=GENEID&DATA=3630) copied and pasted by the program user into a TextField constructed via importing Swing. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I forgot to notify you - apologies @Makri.

Comment: I am a little confused as to what the question really is, but it seems to me that a codon is pre-determined (being stuff like amino-acids and alike? Arrest me if I'm wrong, I am not good with bio)? What I do believe your question is, is: 
You have a string of nucletides as seen in your link. This will be pasted into a textField, and read by the program from there. then you need to split up the string into codons, and then what?

Answer (score 0):

By your rather insufficient explanation of the question, I would say the approach is to first, create the object (the class CodonObject), which I will not write here since it is not a specific part of the question. Then create a method inside the object called... Whatever you want, maybe something like createCodonFromNucleotides(char a, char b, char c) call it like this: CodonObject.createCodonFromNucleotides, and inside the parameter, send in the char-values you want. It will be like this when you call it:

```
String returnedString=CodonObject.createCodonFromNucleotides(char a, char b, char c);
```

Then, inside the method you can use numerous approaches, one is to first put them into an array (if you know that it will always be 3 chars that is entered), and then use the charArray.toString()-method. 
I hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try this method

```
String s = new StringBuilder().append(char1).append(char2).append(char3).toString();
```